# How to check MediaPlayer is ready to call start() | Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, prepared-statement, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I want to check if the prepare() is finished to call start(),Because I sometime when I press the start button it starts playing but I can't pause or stop the player.

**Now: I need to wait for a while to make sure that prepare() is finished and it is ready to start and then press start button.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set OnPreparedListener to the media player instance and inside onPrepared() start the media player.

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    player.start();
                
                }
            });
```

[developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)